# Polishing a mongodb query

Tags: java, mongodb

This is my current query: Using Java+mongoDB

```
    {
    BasicDBObject select = new BasicDBObject();
    select.put("info.name.fn", 1);

    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(new BasicDBObject(), select);
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }
```

It gives an output as:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "123"} , "info" : { "name" : { "fn" : "foo"}}}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "123"} , "info" : { "name" : { "fn" : "bar"}}}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "123"} , "info" : { "name" : { "fn" : "baz"}}}
```

_ids changed to accommodate the output. My question is, what query do I give to get the output as:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

Is it even possible? Or does every query always return it in the above format? I cant run a distinct() because there are duplicate names.

Thanks.

Comment: I also tried cursor.next.get("info.name.fn") but it returns null.

Comment: I think you have to break it down into a chain of three gets. That is a potential improvement request though for the Java API. Maybe ask about it on the MongoDB mailing list. Someone will already have thought of this, though, and it was probably discarded because it causes trouble somewhere.

Comment: ok, i will post it on the mongodb-user GG. thanks.

Comment: also mention all the casting you have to do.

Comment: Not sure how Java and Mongo work together, but you should check out the "Retrieving a Subset of Fields" section in the docs. This allows you to limit what your query retrieves. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RetrievingaSubsetofFields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal query result you can get is the one you show above.

You do not have to print all of that, though.

```
 System.out.println(cursor.next().get("info").get("name").get("fn"));
```

Comment: yes, that worked. except that i had to add a BasicBSONObject cast twice. now it looks like this: 
System.out.println(((BasicBSONObject) ((BasicBSONObject) cursor.next().get("info")).get("name")).get("fn"))

Comment: Oh. That casting is ugly. But I suppose there is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: yeah. i will keep the question unanswered just a bit longer to see if i can hook some other answers. posted it on mongodb-user too.